# Proof Verification : Continuous mapping is determined by the values on a dense subset.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Just wanted to check this proof real quick, I haven't found this solution.

$E$ is dense in $X$. Let $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous maps. ( X and Y are metric spaces). Suppose $f(p)=g(p) \forall p \in E$. Then $f(x)=g(x) \forall x \in X$

My solution: Fix $x \in X/E$ and $f(p)$ in $f(X)$. Let $\varepsilon$ be arbitrary. Then there is a $\delta_f$ such that $d_Y(f(p),f(x)) < \varepsilon$ whenever $d_X(p,x)< \delta_f$. Similarly there is a $\delta_g$ such that $d_Y(g(p),g(x))<\varepsilon$ whenever $d_X(p,x)<\delta_g$.

Set $\delta = \mathrm{min}(\delta_g, \delta_f)$. Then for every $x$ such that $d_X(x,p)< \delta$, we have $$d_Y(g(x),f(x))\leq d_Y(g(x),g(p)+d_Y(g(p),f(x))$$
$$=d_Y(g(x),g(p)+d_Y(f(p),f(x))$$ $$< 2\varepsilon$$.

Arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$ implies the result.

Thanks for your help!!

P.S : All the solutions I have seen till now involve sequences so I wanted to see if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is basically correct except some typos in your proof. Let me reorganize this for you:

Fix an arbitrary $x\in X\setminus E$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta_f>0$ such that $$d_X(x,x')<\delta_f\implies d_Y(f(x),f(x'))<\varepsilon.$$
Similarly, we can find a $\delta_g>0$ such that $$d_X(x,x')<\delta_g\implies d_Y(g(x),g(x'))<\varepsilon.$$
Note we set $\delta:=\min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$. **Since $E$ is dense in $X$, there exists $p\in E$ such that $d_X(x,p)<\delta$**. As a result, by triangle inequality, (*You also made a mistake here.*)$$d_Y(f(x),g(x))\leq d_Y(f(x),f(p))+d_Y(f(p),g(p))+d_Y(g(x),g(p))<2\varepsilon.$$
By setting $\varepsilon\to 0$, we indeed have $f(x)=g(x)$. Q.E.D.

**P.S.** An alternative way is to show that the fixed point set $\{x\in X\mid f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed, or equivalently the set $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ is open. Recall that the closure of any dense subset is the whole space.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!